# Negative lookahead with capturing groups

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, backreference, capturing-group

I'm attempting this challenge:

https://regex.alf.nu/4

I want to match all strings that don't contain an ABBA pattern.

Match:

```
aesthophysiology
amphimictical
baruria
calomorphic
```

Don't Match

```
anallagmatic
bassarisk
chorioallantois
coccomyces
abba
```

Firstly, I have a regex to determine the ABBA pattern.

```
(\w)(\w)\2\1
```

Next I want to match strings that don't contain that pattern:

```
^((?!(\w)(\w)\2\1).)*$
```

However this matches everything.

If I simplify this by specifying a literal for the negative lookahead:

```
^((?!agm).)*$
```

The the regex does not match the string "anallagmatic", which is the desired behaviour.

So it looks like the issue is with me using capturing groups and back-references within the negative lookahead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
^(?!.*(.)(.)\2\1).+$

    ^^
```

You can use a `lookahead` here.See demo.The lookahead you created was correct but you need add `.*` so that it cannot appear anywhere in the string.

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/39

Your approach will also work if you make the first group `non capturing`.

```
^(?:(?!(\w)(\w)\2\1).)*$

 ^^
```

See demo.It was not working because  `\2` `\1` were different than what you intended.In your regex they should have been `\3` and `\2`.

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/40

Comment: I see, that makes perfect sense. Thanks for the explanation. I've also never come across the Regex101 site before, that will be useful if I ever have to post examples again.