# regular expression to match regular expression flags "ismU"

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to match "ismU" flags.
The requirements are as follows:
1) each character appears at most only once
2) The character can appear in any order: "is", "si", "mi", "smi", "Uims"

The requirement 1) lead to "?" quantifier, and 2) leads to "|" alternation.

"i?|U?|m?|s?" could only apply to length of 1.

"[imsU]{1,4}" could apply to length of 4 but it accepts duplicated flag(e.g., "ii")

Test cases to be True:[ "i", "im", "mi", "Ums", "iUsm"];
Test cases to be False:[ "I", "mm"].

Comment: Probably easier to just use string functions.

Comment: With a back-reference: `^(?!.*(.).*\1)[imsU]+$`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I like it. post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using a negative lookahead assertion in which you test if a character is repeated (anywhere). To express that, you need a capture group `(.)` and a reference to the capture `\1`.

```
^(?!.*(.).*\1)[imsU]+$
```

Note that you don't have to use a quantifier more precise than `+` since the lookahead has already check there isn't a same character twice and since there are only four different characters in the character class.

However, to be more efficient (in particular to avoid to test `.*(.).*\1` on a long string), you can also write the pattern like this:

```
^(?!.{0,2}(.).{0,2}\1)[imsU]{1,4}$
```

Comment: To all wondering using negative lookahead in regex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862316/negative-lookahead-with-capturing-groups   This link shows the example of using capturing groups in the whole regular expression besides the lookahead.  Here is mine for finishing my job: re.compile("(\(\?(?!.{0,2}(.).{0,2}\\2)[imsU]{1,4}\))\^(.*)")