# Negative lookahead with capture groups

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have text like

```
question 1, chapter 1
...
solution for question 1, chapter 1
...
question 2, chapter 1
...
```

I am trying to figure out how to detect, via ***"VS Code search and replace"*** regex, questions that do not have a solution. I have tried variations of `question (\d+), chapter (\d+)\n(.*\n+)solution for question (?!\1)`. The idea is I would match, if question 3 does not have a solution, question 3 when it would negate at "solution for question 4". This does not seem to work. I'm unsure why.

I have looked at a few [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862316), but I can't figure it out with that information

Comment: Perhaps [question\s+(\d+),\s+chapter\s+(\d+)(?!.*question\s+\1\s+chapter\s+\2)](https://regex101.com/r/0oq0yd/1)?

Comment: @Nick - missed a comma in the initial question and that seems to break this formula

Comment: @Nick - I tried that, but it seems to match [more than what we want](https://regex101.com/r/3pUI5p/1)

Comment: Ah yeah... Is the text format fixed exactly?

Comment: @Nick yes it is

Comment: A negative lookbehind for `solution for` at the beginning should work then https://regex101.com/r/5rkp1M/1

Comment: Without crossing question or solution `^question\s+(\d+),\s+chapter\s+(\d+)(?!(?:\n(?!question |solution ).*)*\nsolution for question \1)` See https://regex101.com/r/FYV81X/1

Comment: @bohemian what does this have to do with VS Code? Or did you not actually put that there? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383668/997587

Comment: @starball there was a comment posted that identified the relevant tool/language, which is important/essential to know when answering regex questions, as "VS Code search and replace" and that was deleted as "no longer needed" due to that tag being added to the question.

Comment: Try `(?<!solution for )question\s+(\d+),\s+chapter\s+(\d+)\n\.\.\.\n(?!solution)`.  Strictly for your input example.  Or `(?<!solution for )question\s+(\d+),\s+chapter\s+(\d+)\n(\.\.\.)*\n(?!solution)` for a looser input.

Comment: Slightly better : `(?<!solution for )question\s+(\d+),\s+chapter\s+(\d+)(?!\n(\.\.\.)*\nsolution)`

Comment: @starball Editors differ in the regex engine they use.  Even vscode's find in a file is different than a search across files in terms of allowable regex's.  Vscode also has unique handling of newlines in its regex's.  So knowing the editor is always helpful.

Comment: @Mark yep. I'm aware of that. I once wrote an answer post about it only to get the Q dup closed and the info moved to the closer's answer :P. I just didn't see the comment about this being a VS Code question. I think Bohemian deleted it before I could see it. I prefer when questions make clear how tags are relevant in an organic way if not obvious. Even still, the problem is there: are they writing a regex for find widget? or search view? they have different support for lookaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the search box in an opened file, you might use a negative lookahead to not cross matching lines that start with either `question`  or `solution`

```
^question\s+(\d+),\s+chapter\s+(\d+)(?!(?:\r?\n(?!question |solution ).*)*\r?\nsolution for question \1)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `question\s+(\d+),` match `questions`, then 1+ whitespace chars and capture 1+ digits in **group 1**
- `\s+chapter\s+` Match `chapter` between 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\d+)` Capture 1+ digits in **group 2**
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is to the right is not

  - `(?:\r?\n(?!question |solution ).*)*`
  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `solution for question \1` Match `solution for question`  followed by the value captured in group 1 using a backreference `\1`
- `)` Close the lookahead

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4hZohK/1)

[image]